# How to change/remove paste on middle click?

Tags: mouse, clipboard

**Question:**

How to remove the "paste" feature of the middle button?

I am not asking to remove the middle button from the device (as many pages show as a solution) because I use this middle button for several operations like opening a tab on firefox, or whatever else.

Just to remove the "paste" operation by default.

**Background:**

Middle button is easy to press by mistake, and for a programmer, this kind of error could easily carry 2h looking for strange bugs, or worse, a crash 2 weeks later, or even worse, a comment in code with personal information, etc..

I am pretty fast to use Ctrl+V, so I do not need this dangerous feature.

**Additional information:**

I am currently using Linux OpenSuse with KDE. The version does not seem important, but I could provide it if requested.

Comment: There is no global setting, each application decides what it does with the middle button. Pasting is a convention, not a system feature.

Comment: P.S. If you find yourself pressing the middle button by accident, get a better mouse. You can find a decent mouse for about $5.

Comment: @Gilles: I have a quite decent mouse, this is not the problem. My fingers are the problem: as a human, I am not perfect, I make typos while writing and some times, I also click by mistake or in the wrong place. I just found this "convention" stupid from a user perspective. Like the Alt+right-click to resize in kde. I could probably explain why, but that would not fit in a comment. Thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could do the trick:

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```

source: http://jaredrobinson.com/blog/howto-disable-middle-mouse-paste-in-linux/

Comment: "I am not asking to remove the middle button"
It actually remove the middle-button pasting, but also remove the middle-button from any other gesture or use.

Comment: my mistake, i misread. I thought you used a wheel as a third button... did you try that ? http://wiki.mbirth.de/know-how/software/linux/remapping-mouse-buttons.html

Comment: I will have a look, possibly some of those tricks can help :-) Is still consider this feature should be something easier to configure.