# gnome/gtk: disable middle click paste via terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell, gtk

**Configuration:** Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, GNOME Tweaks 3.28.1 (I believe it's pre-installed in 18.04), Middle Click Paste: OFF

**Problem:** It's not disabling middle click paste, although it worked once (until after the first restart with that option set to OFF).

**Question:** What is the actual shell command that disables the MCP feature?

**Reasoning behind the question:** I figured that GNOME Tweaks is executing that command by toggling that ON/OFF option and that it may use the wrong command now. This might be due to a dist-upgrade that changed the command.

Comment: I am providing a partial solution to this problem. Using the gnome-tweak-tool the middle-click paste can be disabled for anything Gnome provides. However, it seems to be a convention of software developers to include the middle-click paste into their applications. For Firefox type about:config into the address bar, click away the warning, then search for middlemouse.paste and set it to false. For Pycharm, go to File, Settings, Keymap, Editor Actions, Paste from X Clipboard, remove the shortcut there. If this comment helped you, please upvote the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underneath, `Tweaks` alters the `dconf` key

```
/org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-enable-primary-paste
```

You can do the same in terminal, either via `dconf` (e.g. to turn it off):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/gtk-enable-primary-paste false
```

or via `gsettings` (e.g. to turn it back on):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste true
```

Comment: This isn't working in Ubuntu 18.04 (either through tweak UI or these cli commands).  Any ideas what changed?

Comment: @MichaelJackson - it worked and still works fine here. I don't use Ubuntu.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question. :(

Comment: The question is specifically about Ubuntu 18.04. Your solution does not work in Ubuntu. Saying "I don't use Ubuntu" does not help either.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov -  not really, the _actual question_, if you read the post, is: _"**Question**: What is the actual shell command that disables the MCP feature?"_ and my post answers exactly that question and not follow-up questions like "why doesn't this work in Ubuntu?"

Comment: @don_crissti Please read the first three words of question body. Your command does NOT disable middle click paste on Ubuntu 18.04 (and earlier versions, for that matter). And if it did, Gnome Tweaks would work as well, so the command wouldn't be necessary in the first place.

Comment: @don_crissti The point of my rant is that there are people looking for ways of disabling middle click paste on Ubuntu and Mint. On TrackPoint laptops (Lenovo & IBM) middle click paste is absolute nightmare. So people google for solution but are only able to find false solutions like yours to no avail.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov - *I never said* my command disabled middle click paste in Ubuntu. There is _absolutely no mention of Ubuntu_ in my post. Again, my post answers the question _as stated by the OP_. I can understand that you're frustrated but you should head to Ubuntu bug tracker and tell them to stop crippling GNOME (which is already crippled by birth...)

Comment: "as stated by the OP" -- the acceptation was obviously a mistake by an inexperienced, one-time user. The information on how to disable MCP is available everywhere on the internet. The point of asking the same question for 1000th time here was that none of existing solutions (including yours) work in Ubuntu. This question is Ubuntu-specific. Did you earn your 47K rep by not reading questions and providing irrelevant answers?

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov - I guess so...

Comment: For those wanting a workaround that actually works on Ubuntu 18.04, this seems to work  on my test system: https://askubuntu.com/a/1195487/116968

Answer (score 2):

This [askubuntu.com answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195487/116968) using `xdotool` and `xbindkeys` seems to work as advertised on my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

The specific configuration maps the middle button (or scroll wheel) click to double-click on primary button which effectively stops the undesired paste action.

Quoting the askubuntu.com answer, for convenience:

> OS: Ubuntu 18:04
> Required Packages: `xdotool` and `xbindkeys`
>
> you can install these packages with `sudo apt install xdotool xbindkeys`
>
> gedit .xbindkeysrc
>
> Paste the below content
>
> ```
> "xdotool click --repeat 2 1"
> b:2
> ```
>
> Save the file and run `xbindkeys --poll-rc`
>
> now your Middle Click should work as double click.

The original answer also addresses Unity differences.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the middle button pasting even though I turned it off in the `dconf` editor.

It turned out that the problem was only persisting in Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird. They seem to have this functionality enabled by default as well.

This is how you can turn it off:

**Firefox:**
Type `about:config` into the URL/search bar, click 'I accept the risk', search for `middlemouse.paste` and set it to `false`

**Thunderbird:**
Go to `Preferences > Advanced > General > Config Editor`, search for `middlemouse.paste` and set it to `false`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Ubuntu, and I found an answer that also works on Centos [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250255/how-to-change-remove-paste-on-middle-click).

xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'

If you have more mouse buttons, you keep adding them; this allows the pointer to be mapped to a different action, but middle mouse is kind of a pain now that we aren't using ancient mice with springs that require a kilogram of force. :)

Comment: This is this only solution that worked for me on Ubuntu.