# How to stop trackpoint scroll button from pasting

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, wayland, void-linux

I have a Dell Latitude 7480 and I run Void with Gnome Wayland (v41.3 at the time of my writing). I use the trackpoint heavily, but pressing the middle (scroll) button without moving the trackpoint causes the computer to paste from the middle-click clipboard. This causes lots of accidental pastes, which is very annoying and a privacy disaster.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is a [gnome setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4507/how-do-i-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste) and works e.g. on Ubuntu. But it only works partially on Void. One way to change it is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste false
```

On void this works for e.g. Gedit. On the other hand Firefox and Chrome seem to ignore the setting.
In Firefox it is [possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443066/gnome-gtk-disable-middle-click-paste-via-terminal) to change `middlemouse.paste` in `about:config` to toggle the behavior.

Instead of gsettings, you can use graphical tools, e.g. `dconf-editor` or `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Maybe someone can come up with a better solution than doing the configuration in the browser.

Comment: Yeah I'd already tried this, and didn't observe any change. On close inspection, it seems to work for some apps (Gedit notably) but not Chrome or Firefox :(

Comment: Ok, thanks for that extra information. Maybe I will have time to test in a vm with void.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your error. Only idea I found so far: In Firefox `about:config` disable `middlemouse.paste`. Found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443066/gnome-gtk-disable-middle-click-paste-via-terminal). 

It is more of a work around though. 
Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out, why the settings works correctly on Ubuntu, but not on void.