# How to restore middle button functionality?

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to remove pasting on clicking middle mouse button, so I read this question
[How to change/remove paste on middle click?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250255/how-to-change-remove-paste-on-middle-click?newreg=592865255a6347b996fc2a902db72d2e)

But after doing command

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```

Middle mouse click stopped doing anything.
How can I enable it?

And if you know, how can I disable pasting with it, but keep other functions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest resetting to the default settings for the pointer.

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = default'
```

As demonstrated from *[xmodmap(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap)*